# Public data to practice data analysis skills

Tags: resource-recommendations, data-analysis, data

Apologies if this is the wrong place to ask this, but I am currently trying to brush up on my data analysis skill in python as I am applying to data science jobs. I am trying to find some data that I can practice on, but would like it to be physics themed as I have a bit more intuition about that than I do with some of the public data I have found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com) has physics data sets for download.
[A search link](https://www.kaggle.com/search?q=physics+tag%3A%22physics%22+in%3Adatasets).

The data sets include collections that stem from supporting information from scientific publications, and Kaggle can thus serve as a central platform to search for large scientific data sets (that otherwise could sometimes be behind journal pay walls or found on individual researchers web sites or, more and more commonly github pages). There are also large data sets that were used in competitions in finding most predictive machine learning models, e.g. to help the search for the Higgs boson at CERN ([Link to article in Symmetry Magazine](https://www.symmetrymagazine.org/article/july-2014/the-machine-learning-community-takes-on-the-higgs)).

A majority of datasets is available in plain comma-separated value (CSV) files and thus easily parsed with any programming language or data analysis tool.

Answer (score 2):

[JPL Horizons](https://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/horizons/) has 20,000 years worth of Solar System data that's freely available and easy to access in various ways.

> The JPL Horizons on-line solar system data and ephemeris computation service provides access to key solar system data and flexible production of highly accurate ephemerides for solar system objects (1,148,619 asteroids, 3,775 comets, 210 planetary satellites {includes satellites of Earth and dwarf planet Pluto}, 8 planets, the Sun, L1, L2, select spacecraft, and system barycenters). Horizons is provided by the Solar System Dynamics Group of the Jet Propulsion Laboratory

Horizons data comes from the [Jet Propulsion Laboratory Development Ephemeris](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jet_Propulsion_Laboratory_Development_Ephemeris) series. This is high quality data. It's used by NASA, and the US Naval Observatory.

It's easy to retrieve Horizons data in Python via the [file API](https://ssd-api.jpl.nasa.gov/doc/horizons_file.html). If you'd like to see actual working code using that API, you can find some of my Python Horizons scripts (running in SageMathCell) in
https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/47345/16685 & https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/28036/16685